# can I use string and integer in while loop in python?

Tags: python

Hello I am new in Python and maybe it is stupid question but can you help me with this code?

```
while True:
k = int(input("type: "))
l = k % 2
if l==0:
     print("luwi")
elif l != 0:
     print("kenti")
```

i want to add elif where is said that if k == "exit" code breaks
how make system to read not only integers but strings as well?or it is impossible?
P.s I am very new in python :D

Comment: @jarmod Please don't link to the Python 2 documentation, if it it's otherwise the same as the Python 3 version: https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would get an error with int(input("type: ")) when entering a non-numeric string.

Try:

```
while True:
    s = input("type: ")  # User inputs string
    try:
        k = int(s)       # tries converting string to int (exception if unsuccessful)
        l = k % 2
        if l==0:
            print("luwi")
        elif l != 0: 
            print("kenti")
    except:               # exception tells you entry was not an integer
        if s == "exit":   
            break         # entered exit
        else:
            print('Enter a number or "exit"')  # ask user to enter number or exit
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be very careful with the  datatype problem. You have to make sure that when k compare with an other variable they have the same datatype. Here are few functions that could change the data type. `str()`, `int()`

Answer (score 0):

How about checking for `exit` first, and then continuing to convert to `int` after that?

```py
while True:
    k = input("type: ")
    if k == 'exit':
        break
    else:
        k = int(k)
    l = k % 2
    if l == 0:
        print("luwi")
    elif l != 0:
        print("kenti")
```

Comment: Thank you very much